# Git pre-push hook executed on both "merge" and "push"?

Tags: git, githooks

I created a git hook - `pre-push.sh`.

However, i noticed it gets executed on both `git merge` and `git push`.

Is this normal? If so, is there a way to apply it exclusively to `git push`?

my hook looks like this:

```
branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
if [[ ${branch} == 'develop' || ${branch} == 'release/*' ]]
then 
...
```

And i merged `release/1` into `develop`.

Does that make sense that it ran twice then?

Comment: No, it's not normal. That would be a bug; the Git folks would fix it quickly. Do you have a reproducer for it?

Comment: @torek i updated my post with a bit more details. Is this still not normal?

Comment: This doesn't show the hook running on `git merge`. To show that, have the hook print something to standard output or standard error, e.g., `echo HOOK JUST RAN 1>&2` to print that to stderr. Then, run a `git merge` that merges, while capturing the output. Show the contents of your `.git/hooks/` directory as well as your `core.hooksPath` configuration setting (`git config --get core.hooksPath`) and the contents of any directories in that path, to demonstrate that there is no merge hook that could have printed the string.